# Java why instantiate a class using object?

Tags: java, java-7

I am currently revising for a Java se7 certification and anyone who has done any of these exams knows how ridiculous some of the code samples they use are. Purposely writing code that is awkward to understand.
Recently I have seen alot of code written like this:

```
Object obj=new Animal();
```

What benefit does this provide? I understand this is valid code, however is this just one of those things that you would just never use like alot of the code in the exams? If not when and why would you do this?

Comment: The only reason which comes to mind as to why you would have code like this would be to demonstrate polymorphism in Java. In any practical implementation, using code like that would require a lot of casting.

Comment: It is not a real world pattern (or in very rare cases). It depends what follows the line. Say we see a `obj.toString()`, what would be the output ? It is a exam question, after all, to check if someone has understand the concepts.

Comment: That is for a context in which only the Object aspect plays a role. Like serializing (storing) the object to disk or such. In `List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();` it makes real sence: going by contract i.o. implementation.

Comment: Or maybe the output of a reverse compiler?  If all of the remaining usages of obj were only method arguments that would get cast to object anyway (like getting passed as a Hashtable value, for example.

Comment: At same time, you can often see things like `List x = new ArrayList();` in real code, where you don't want to carry specific implementation type throughout your class. Similar concepts apply, probably exam code is just making things simplier by not using more complex hierarchies.

Comment: It's a multiple choice test with odd questions about odd code, testing your knowledge about edge cases of the language. The intention is not that you learn from this code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something that is not useful. It shows that the Java type system lets you store any object in a variable of type `Object` and not only objects instantiated directly with `new Object()` and this is the simplest example that can demonstrate it.

Every object is a subclass of the `Object` class. It demonstrates that when you declare a type of a variable to be of some type, then you can put there not only that exact type (`Object` in your example) but any subtype (`Animal` in your example).

While using the base class for all objects may not seem useful, a more complicated class hierarchy may demonstrate it better.

Let's say that you have more subclasses of `Animal`: `Dog`, `Cat`, `Hamster`. Now let's say that you have also many subclasses of `Dog`, `Cat` and `Hamster` (if there are any different kinds of hamsters).

```
public class Animal { // implicitly extends Object
    // ...
}
public class Dog extends Animal {
    // ...
}
public class Cat extends Animal {
    // ...
}
public class Hamster extends Animal {
    // ...
}
public class Hamster extends Animal {
    // ...
}
Labrador extends Dog {
    // ...
}
// etc.
```

Now, if you want to have an `Animal` in a variable you can write:

```
Animal animal = new Cat();
```

or:

```
Animal animal = new Labrador();
```

Now, the exact code from your question:

```
Object obj = new Animal();
```

can be useful in few different ways:

If you want to be sure that you are using the interface exposed by the `Object` class and nothing added later in the inheritance chain.

You can also have e.g. an array of 5 dogs:

```
Dog[] dogs = new Dogs[5];
```

where you can put dogs, but not cats or hamsters.

You can have an array of animals where you can put any animals, but not other Objects like e.g. numbers:

```
Animal[] animals = new Animals[5];
```

Now, why would you have such an array? For example if your `Animal` class has a `getName` method then you can always run:

```
animals[2].getName();
```

no matter which kind of animal is there. But if the `Dog` class has a method `bark()` but the `Cat` class doesn't have it, then you won't be able to run:

```
animals[2].bark();
```

(not without explicit casting) even if a `Dog` instance was indeed stored in animals under that index, because the compiler doesn't know what will be in that array during the run time - all it can guarantee is that there will be some animal there so you can only call those methods that are sure to be present for all animals.

This may sound silly but you'll see that it is indeed used in a lot of places. For example in GUI programming you can have a scroll panel in which you can put any component like a button or text field, but not any object at all, which is guaranteed by exactly that mechanism - for example a `JPanel` object has a method `add()` that take components of class `Component` but those doesn't have to be created with `new Component()` but can be e.g. a `JLabel` or another `JPanel`.

Comment: I fail to see how this answers the question. If this were to use `Object[]` then maybe I could stretch my imagination, but to me, in its current form, it doesn't really address the question at all.

Comment: I agree to what Polygnome said, the question explicitly states why the example casts to Object, not why or how casting works or is used.

Comment: @Polygnome thanks for your comment. I updated my answer.

Comment: @tringel Good point. I updated my answer to be more clear. Please tell me if you have any more suggestions. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

It demonstrates that `Object` is a base class (parent class) of `Animal`.

In other words, even though you didn't write

```
public class Animal extends Object {
}
```

The compiler added in the "extends Object"; because, all classes extend `Object`.

This is true for all classes in the Java language, and while the example is poorly chosen for the purposes of teaching, it is (in some ways) a so-so way of testing if you understand such a concept.  Odds are you will not use this technique in regular development.

Comment: Note that you are not really instantiating using Object, you are capturing the Animal's reference as an Object.  Probably you know that, but just described it less clearly than possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is basically a dynamic binding..
Object obj= new Animal(); it means that you are creating object for animal class and its address is stored in reference variable obj..
Object obj means you can only access the function of object class through animal class object....
let us understand by this a small program

```
class Object
{
    void fun()
    {
        System.out.println("hello");
    }
}

class Animal extends Object
{
    void fun1()
    {
        System.out.println("hi");
    }

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Object obj = new Animal();
        obj.fun();
    }
}
```

output-hello

Answer (score 0):

This can be useful if the use of `obj` variable does not depend on it being an `Animal`. For example, suppose you pass the new object to a function that prints it using `toString()`. Then the exact class of `obj` is not relevant.and the code illustrates this.